# C# RSA Decrypt (The parameter is incorrect)

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

Im using the following code to encrypt and decrypt a small file using RSA and safely transfer them using usb drive (I know, RSA is not the best for encrypting files...)

But for some reason it wont work anymore. Im trying to decrypt my file and it keeps throwing a "The parameter is incorrect" exception

The keys did not changed (both private and public)
The code did not changed (both encrypt and decrypt)

Anybody have an idea of what could be wrong?

```
static int SegmentLength = 213; //85; // keysize/8 -42 -1

    public static byte[] EncryptRSA(string publicKey, byte[] data)
    {
        CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 };
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParams);


        rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey));

        //byte[] plainBytes = data;
        //byte[] encryptedBytes = rsaProvider.Encrypt(plainBytes, false);

        var length = data.Length / SegmentLength + 1;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int lengthToCopy;
            if (i == length - 1 || data.Length < SegmentLength)
                lengthToCopy = data.Length - (i * SegmentLength);
            else
                lengthToCopy = SegmentLength;


            //var segment = decryptedData.Substring(i * SegmentLength, lengthToCopy);
            byte[] segment = new byte[lengthToCopy];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(data, i * SegmentLength, segment, 0, lengthToCopy);
            byte[] encrypted = rsaProvider.Encrypt(segment,false);
            stream.Write(encrypted,0,encrypted.Length);
        }

        return stream.ToArray();
    }

private const int EncryptedLength = 256; //keylen * 8

    public static byte[] DecryptRSA(string privateKey, byte[] data)
    {
        CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 };
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParams);

        rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey));

        var rsainfo = rsaProvider.ExportParameters(true);

        var length = data.Length / EncryptedLength;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            byte[] segment = new byte[EncryptedLength];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(data, i * EncryptedLength, segment, 0, EncryptedLength);
            byte[] decrypted = rsaProvider.Decrypt(segment, false);

            stream.Write(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);

        }

        //string plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

        return stream.ToArray();
    }
```

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException occurred
>     HResult=0x80070057   Message=Parâmetro incorreto.
>
> Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle
>   pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey, Boolean
>   fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[]
>   rgb, Boolean fOAEP)    at Decriptor.Program.DecryptRSA(String
>   privateKey, Byte[] data) in
>   Program.cs:line 149 
>   at Decriptor.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   Program.cs:line 45
>
> - rsainfo {System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters}    System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters
> - D   {byte[256]} byte[]
> - DP  {byte[128]} byte[]
> - DQ  {byte[128]} byte[]
> - Exponent    {byte[3]}   byte[]
> - InverseQ    {byte[128]} byte[]
> - Modulus {byte[256]} byte[]
> - P   {byte[128]} byte[]
> - Q   {byte[128]} byte[]

Comment: In case you aren't aware, using RSA as a block cipher is an incredibly unintelligent thing to do.  Maybe you should take this opportunity to introduce hybrid encryption.

Comment: This is what Im doing, the program will encrypt many files using AES and save the symmetric key to a file then encrypt this file using an asymmetric key

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution?